# Receive video from a source, preprocess and stream live preview to the client | ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, video-streaming, ip-camera, ml.net

I need to implement a server that gets video from some source for example IPCamera
then preprocess the image and streams it down to the client (if requested).

I already implemented the part with processing, it accepts a single frame (bitmap) and returns the processed bitmap. What I'm struggling with is the part of receiving video from the camera and then streaming it to the client.

What would be the right way to do it?
What libraries do you recommend using?
I use ASP.NET Core for the Server part, and Angular/React for the Client.

*I tried to implement gRPC but a gRPC-Web client for typescript seems to be a pain in the ass.*

**Edit: 02.08.2022**

What I achieved so far:

I figured out how to receive image output from the camera.

I found out **RTSP** Client for C#. Source: [C# RTSP Client for .NET](https://github.com/BogdanovKirill/RtspClientSharp)
It works pretty fine. I can receive output with small to no delay, and I use my phone to emulate the RTSP camera/server.

So RTSP Client receives raw frames (in my case H.264 IFrame/PFrame). The problem is I need to decode those frames preferably to Bitmap because I use **YoloV4** ONXX Model for object detection.
Here's how I set up YoloV4 with ML.Net. Source: [Machine Learning with ML.NET – Object detection with YOLO](https://rubikscode.net/2021/04/05/machine-learning-with-ml-net-object-detection-with-yolo/)

To decode raw frames I use **FFMpeg** (sadly I didn't find any working FFMpeg package that would work with .NET Core, I tried AForge.Net, Accord but in both packages, the FFMPEG namespace is missing after installing for some reason, so I dug through Github and took this project [FrameDecoderCore](https://github.com/i-TechSoftware/RtspClientSharpCore/tree/master/RtspClientSharpCore/FrameDecoderCore)). It's not the best solution but it works. Now I can receive the output and decode it to Bitmap.

Now I'm facing three major issues:

1. How to detect objects without delaying the process of receiving camera output. And how to properly build an onnx model just to predict without training.
2. How to convert processed bitmaps back to a video stream. I also need to be able to save part of it as a video file on disk (video format doesn't matter) whenever the desired object was detected.
3. How to stream processed or unprocessed output to the client when the client wants to see the camera output. - I'm thinking of gRPC here and sending bitmaps and then displaying it on HTML Canvas.

Here's how my service looks at the moment:

```cs
public class CCTVService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly RtspClient _rtspClient;
        private readonly ILogger<CCTVService> _logger;

        private const int streamWidth = 480;
        private const int streamHeight = 640;

        private static readonly FrameDecoder FrameDecoder = new FrameDecoder();
        private static readonly FrameTransformer FrameTransformer = new FrameTransformer(streamWidth, streamHeight);

        public CCTVService(ILogger<CCTVService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _rtspClient = new RtspClient(new ConnectionParameters(new Uri("rtsp://192.168.0.99:5540/ch0")));
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
         {
            using (_rtspClient)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _rtspClient.ConnectAsync(stoppingToken);
                    _logger.LogInformation("Connecting to RTSP");
                }
                catch(RtspClientException clientException)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(clientException.Message);
                    //throw;
                }

                _rtspClient.FrameReceived += (obj, rawFrame) =>
                {
                    if (rawFrame is not RawVideoFrame rawVideoFrame)
                        return;

                    var decodedFrame = FrameDecoder.TryDecode(rawVideoFrame);

                    if (decodedFrame == null) 
                        return;

                    using var bitmap = FrameTransformer.TransformToBitmap(decodedFrame);

                    _logger.LogInformation($"Timestamp: {new DateTimeOffset(rawFrame.Timestamp).ToUnixTimeSeconds()} Timestamp-diff: {new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds() - new DateTimeOffset(rawFrame.Timestamp).ToUnixTimeSeconds()}");

                    // save bitmaps | Test
                    //var t = new Thread(() =>
                    //{
                    //    using var bitmap = FrameTransformer.TransformToBitmap(decodedFrame);
                    //    var name = "./test/" + new DateTimeOffset(rawFrame.Timestamp).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString() + " - " + new Random().NextInt64().ToString() + ".bmp";
                    //    bitmap.Save(name);
                    //});
                    //t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                    //t.Start();
                };

                try
                {
                    await _rtspClient.ReceiveAsync(stoppingToken);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // swallow
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the snippet where you are struggling with? It would be great to check with your sample.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks for your interest in the topic. I have updated the post. I don't have much code right now. I have more questions than answers so I'm doing research on this topic before I start.
If it will appear to be a huge challenge I think I'll change the technology and architecture. Although I hope to implement it in C# with client/server architecture.

Answer (score 1):

So I can't really help with part 2 and 3 of your question but with ML.NET, one of the things you might consider is batching the predictions. Instead of preprocessing them one at a time, you could collect 10-20 frames and then instead of using `PredictionEngine`, use the `Transform` passing it in an `IDataView` instead of a `Bitmap`.

Here are some samples of using ONNX models inside applications. The WPF sample might be of interest since it uses a webcam to capture inputs. I believe it uses the native Windows APIs, so different than how you'd do it for web but it might be worth looking at anyway.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/main/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/ObjectDetection-Onnx